# How do I Unit Test Runnable Class?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Considering this code

```
class ReportSenderRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      executeTasks();
    }

    private void executeTasks() {
      try {
        runTask1();
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        logError(ReportStatus.COMPRESSING, e.getMessage());
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_COMPRESSION;
      } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
        logError(ReportStatus.COMPRESSING, e.getMessage());
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_COMPRESSION;
      }

      try {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.SENDING;
        runTask2();
       } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_SENDING;
      }

      try {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.SUBMITTING_REPORT;
        runTask3();
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        reportStatus = ReportStatus.EXCEPTION_IN_SUBMITTING_REPORT;
      }

      System.out.println("Report Sender completed");
      reportStatus = ReportStatus.DONE;
    }

    private void logError(final ReportStatus status, final String cause) {
      LOGGER.error("{} - {}", status, cause);
    }
  }
```

This code is passed to `ExecutorService` to run.

```
  private void submitJob() {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(new ReportSenderRunnable());
    System.out.println("started Report Sender Job");
  }
```

Assuming `runTask1()`, `runTask2()` and `runTask3()` are already tested somewhere else, How can I test this code?

I am so very confused because I am learning multi-threaded programming now

Thank you

Comment: `new ReportSenderRunnable().run()`?

Comment: @Lashane, I am looking to `JUnit` way of testing multi-threaded code

Comment: @daydreamer I wonder if it is appropriate to test it multi-threaded.  What you are supposed to test is only the logic in `run()`, which you do not need to have it tested multi-threaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to test like this

```
public class TestMultiThread {
@Test
public void testThread(){
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(new ReportSenderRunnable());
    System.out.println("started Report Sender Job");
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how can I test my code when I already pass a new Runnable

Comment: you can use just as your code
    executorService.execute(new ReportSenderRunnable());