# How to mock run() method of Runnable subclass with required parameters

Tags: java, runnable

I have an Event class which implements Runnable interface. How can write unit tests for this class ?

```
@Component("Event")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class Event implements Runnable {

    private final Person person;
    private final Student student;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {

    //somecode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Unit Test Runnable Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640297/how-do-i-unit-test-runnable-class)

Comment: If you want to _mock_ the `run` method, then which method are you trying to test?

Comment: @k314159 I want to test the run method , and mock the external calls inside this method.
@MarcoLettieri I am not able to create an object of this class by doing `new DayChangeEvent()` , i guess maybe due to @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into multiple posts, I finally got the solution.
Because of the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` paramater creating an object of Event class will not happen through no arguement constructor.
Code inside unit test case class :

```
@Mock Person person;

@Mock Student student;

@Injectmocks Event event;

@Test
private void testfunction(){

   Event event = new Event(person,student);

   event.run();

   //mockito.verify()...
}
```

Comment: You could add `@NoArgsConstructor` too or use a Builder, but your fields would then be null by default